# HttpWebRequest with GET: 401 unauthorized

Tags: c#, email, networking, soap, httpwebrequest

I found some problem with httpWebRequest, I've read all the same issues on other forums, but answers don't seem to work. My code:

```
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse resp;
wr.ContentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"; 
wr.Method = "GET";
wr.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
resp = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
```

The remote server returned an error: `(401) Unauthorized.`
Response says there's no auth token in cookies. I can receieve this token using my auth request with POST method. I even tried to put it to CookieContainer by `"new Cookie ("authToken",token_value)".` But the result is the same - `error 401`. Does anybody know the solution?

Thanx.

I use Zimbra web server, have an access to control it. .NET 4.0. My url is the path to .eml file I need to download. To specify the file I need to add some GET parameters: id and part. So the whole address looks like http://someserver.info/service/content/get?id=1&part=1

Comment: Is it possible to tell the following things: 1. What is the URL of the site that you are requesting? 2. What version of the .NET are you using?(can be inappropriate) 3. What is the web server you used? 4. Can you control the web server that you are trying to connect and apply necessary security permissions? Thanks.

Comment: I use Zimbra web server, have an access to control it. .NET 4.0. My url is the path to .eml file I need to download. To specify the file I need to add some GET parameters: id and part. So the whole address looks like http://someserver.info/service/content/get?id=1&part=1

Comment: Did you try that : (if it is possible) connecting the web server with a basic web browser , and debug what is going on with a tool like fiddler(http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) ??

Comment: May be you forget to add a simple webrequest header like Cache-Control: no-cache Authorization: Basic "..." or something like that.

Comment: I added this two header, but the result is the same. I found this topic: http://www.zimbra.com/forums/zimbra-connector-outlook/18195-file-upload-fault.html , but they didn't find the solution. Fiddler shows "error 401: no authtoken cookie" as at link above

Comment: @Alexander B - you should put your solution as an answer and then accept it so that this q appears as finished and for future people encountering the same problem

Comment: When requesting from a web browser, what is the raw view of your request (in fiddler)? And most importantly is it the same as your request which is generated from your C# application. Could you please inform us about these issues? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in the comments and question edits by OP. Moved here. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> The authorization token in Zimbra called `ZM_AUTH_TOKEN` so you need to put your `authtoken` in cookies like this:

```
wr.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
wr.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("ZM_AUTH_TOKEN", rc.AuthToken));
```

> You don't need to put the auth headers then, the request will work